# JGIT clone disconnect red

Tags: jgit

good morning, I'm having a problem.

When I do:

```
git = Git.cloneRepository ()
.setURI (remote)
.setProgressMonitor (monitor)
.setDirectory (new file (local))
//.setBranch(branch)
.setCredentialsProvider (credentials)
.call();
```

and for some reason I disconnected the cable red, there is no way to catch an exception, such as ... "disconnect", "time out" or something similar.

This problem is going to be very common, therefore I have to contemplate it.

Comment: How do you test this?

Comment: is the cloning of a remote repository (git), a local repository, with Java and the JGit library